# LInkedList in C weird error in sizeof(Node)

Tags: c

I am getting an error in the constructor for Node inside the sizeof(Node) saying "type name is not allowed" any thought ? Thank you

---

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    Node *next;
};
struct LinkedList {
    Node *first;
    int size;
};

typedef struct Node Node;
typedef struct LinkedList LinkedList;
//constructor for node
Node* createNode(int data) {
    Node * newNode = malloc(sizeOf(Node));
    if (data != NULL) {
        newNode->data = data;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        return newNode;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: `sizeOf` -> `sizeof`

Comment: `sizeOf` isn’t spelled that way, and (in *C*) you can’t use `Node` without `struct` before the `typedef`.

Comment: Node * newNode = malloc(sizeOf(Node)); Here malloc return void*  . You must convert it to (Node*) like Node * newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeOf(Node));

Comment: @Chuanhang.gu You don't; it is implicit in c

Comment: @user12986714 thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
malloc(sizeOf(Node))
```

should be

```
malloc(sizeof(Node))
```

also I suspect that there are other compiler errors; you have to do

```
struct Node *
```

rather than

```
Node *
```

Comment: i did get compile error. If i use typedef, i still need to write struct everytime ?

Comment: No, but every time *before* you declare the `typedef`

Comment: I tried doing   struct Node * newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node*)); and                    struct Node * newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); But it gives an error saying undefined struct union/Node

Comment: `struct Node {
    int data;
    Node *next;
};` is before the typedef declaration. Noticed something odd?

Comment: Oh it compiled. I'm new to C and aprreciate the help. Thank you so much.

Comment: @user13443636 also (just out of curiosity) what line the compiler is giving an error on? It should give an error as early as you declared `Node *next;` inside your struct declaration